# Is there alternative string literal delimiter for Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

To make a long story short, I have a situation where I sometimes needs to express a Postgresql or MySql query as a string literal in Sql Server using the `OPENQUERY()` function. These queries also commonly have string literals of their own. (*Note that I am* not *using dynamic sql here... the literals in these queries are constants for the query, and I* do *appreciate the difference.*)

In this case, when working on a query, it's common to need to copy/paste what I have stored for Sql Server into a postgresql or MySql query tool, and then clean up the extra single quotes on any literals. When I'm done, I need to copy/paste it back to my source control for the project and into Sql Server, and at this point I need to double-up all of those single quotes again. Messing with those quote characters is a pain, and unfortunately `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` is not an option for me in this circumstance.

Is there another way to denote string literals for Sql Server that I can use to avoid needing to muck about with my quote characters when moving queries back and forth between the query tools for the different databases?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way that I know of to change the SQL Server's string quote character, so you're stuck with having to specify them like you're doing. You could automate the generation of the correct quote characters in your query file though, depending on your database server. For example, one brute force way I've done that with in the past with with Microsoft Excel. One Excel column would contain my core queries, then subsequent Excel columns would transform that column with SUBSTITUTE() functions. Of course you could automate this quite easily if you wanted to do something more elegant.